# Drupal Lookup Path Change

Tags: uri

I am displaying demonstration sites with iFrames and in page--demo.tpl.php I have a possibility to get NID only from path. So I managed demo's number will be the same as NID and now I have a code:

```
print drupal_lookup_path('alias',"demo/".$node->nid);
```

It works correctly but I would like to transfer that link to /node/$node->nid.

Is there any way to do so? I tried to print $node->nid underneath, but it prints wrong number (36 instead of 34).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']); 
$path = explode('/', $path);
print $path[1];
```